# CakePHP Delete Cookie Issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've browsed through other people's issues similar to this, but nothing seems to be exactly like what I am experiencing. Please feel free to reference me to another article if this has been addressed before.

I have written a cookie when a user authenticates that stores some basic user info locally. When the user logs out, I am trying to delete the cookie variable, but is does not delete. If I use the destroy method, then the cookie is removed, but I am curious as to what I am doing wrong here:

Cookie is written like this and is working:

```
function login(){
    if($this->Auth->login($this->data)){
        $this->Cookie->write('User.email',$this->data['User']['email'],true, '1 day');
    }
}
```

However, using the delete function does not work...

```
function logout(){
    $this->Cookie->delete('User');
    if($this->Auth->logout($this->data)){
        //auto redirected
    }
}
```

If I replace delete with destroy, it works.  Is this not working because the cookie data is encrypted?  I'm probably doign something stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using this cookie to persist through sessions. I only want it deleted if the user clicks a logout button.

Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question on my part - I see you are writing User.email and deleting User.  Now, I get that if you had User, it would delete User and User.email, but are you sure that User is there to be found by the delete method?  I'd look there first.

Comment: Based on this article, I should be able to remove the User variable. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1282/Using-the-Component

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for but, you can try setting the cookie's expiry date in the past instead of using delete.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want the cookie to expire unless the user forces a logout. I've achieved the end result I want by using the destroy method, but I'm curious as to how I am using delete incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the source, it looks like this is either a bug or intended behavior.

The CookieComponent class has an internal __values array that it uses to keep track of cookie information.  If you call delete('User.email'), it will remove the 'User' index from the __values array, including all data under the index.

However, it will only unset the cookie named 'User'.  Next time Cake fires up, it will see that a cookie named 'User.email' still exists and load it back into the __values array.

Assuming it's not intended behavior, I wrote a fix and I'll go ahead and submit it to the Cake team.

Comment: I assume you are talking about this bit of code, correct?
if (strpos($key, '.') === false) {
   unset($this->__values[$key]);
   $this->__delete("[$key]");
   return;
  }

Are you checking for a string starting with that key first before proceeding with the delete in your fix?  Then, if you find anything containing the string, are you just looping through the values and deleting them individually?  Just curious.  I'd be interested to follow the bug tracking in order to learn the outcome, if you have that available.

I think you are right though. This has to be a bug.

Comment: Going to mark your answer as the solution.  Bug or not, that is the cause.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Here's what I submitted to the Cake team, including a link to a fix. Yes, I'm just looping through the values.  http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/1651-cookiecomponent-fails-to-delete-sub-indexes

Comment: This appears to have been corrected in CakePHP 1.3.9. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Scott Really? I'm still getting this

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I haven't tried a test, but the release notes claim this was fixed. See the third bullet from the bottom on the release notes page.  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2011/05/21/cakephp_1_3_9_and_2_0_0-alpha_released

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but after asking around a bit it's still happening.