# Cookie destroy not working in CakePHP 2.7

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

Quite straight forward:

```
public function demo(){
    $this->Cookie->delete('Auth.User');
    $this->Cookie->destroy();
    if($this->Cookie->check('Auth.User')){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
    die();
}
```

Getting "yes" all the time. Using CakePHP 2.7.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP Delete Cookie Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655255/cakephp-delete-cookie-issue)

Comment: @JamieBicknell That's an answer from 2011 and they say it was solved in 2.0.0. Not a duplicated of it.

Comment: The problem is probably kinda similar though, deleting/destroying only empties the components `_values` property, `$_COOKIE` is left untouched, causing subsequent checks to not fail, as the value will be retrieved from the superglobal in case it's not available in `_values`. Given that the cookie is being written before `demo()` is being invoked, the check should fail on subsequent requests, otherwise the cookie will remain.

Comment: @ndm I don't really understand it. What are you suggesting to remove the cookie then ? Why the cookie still containing data even when I remove my `Cookie->write` statement?

Comment: You should also remove the `die()`, otherwise the empty/destroyed cookie will never be sent to the client.